# How to put and get group of unknown bytes as a string to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, character-encoding, bytecode

i have unknown bytes its bits start from 00000000 to 11111111
i use every 8 bits as a character, how to add these characters to JSON without error and get them back?
i search a lot but cannot find answer.using  java and java script .

Comment: Use `String.fromCharCode()` to convert a numeric byte to a character, and add it to the string. Then convert the string to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options.

Assuming you're starting with an array of numbers, the simplest method is to just convert to JSON directly. JSON does support arrays of numbers after all.

```
bytes = Array.apply(null, {length:256}).map(function(a, b) {return b;})
JSON.stringify(bytes)
"[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255]"
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(bytes))
Array[256]
```

If you really want to convert it to a string for some reason, Javascript strings are unicode, so they can handle code points 0-255 losslessly.

```
s = bytes.map(function(x) {return String.fromCharCode(x);}).join('')
"
bytes2 = s.split('').map(function(x) {return x.charCodeAt(0);})
Array[256]
```

JSON also supports strings, so you can convert the string to and from JSON if you want to, though I can't imagine why you would.

```
s
"

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ"
JSON.stringify(s)
""\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\u0007\b\t\n\u000b\f\r\u000e\u000f\u0010\u0011\u0012\u0013\u0014\u0015\u0016\u0017\u0018\u0019\u001a\u001b\u001c\u001d\u001e\u001f !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ""
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(s))
"
```